# How display div when increase browser size back?

Tags: html, css

I am displaying a div. when i click close/open then div hides or shows.

What i want is that when the div is hidden and when i increase my browser size to > 767px then the div should display back automatically.

To test it, first decrease the size of the browser then click close so the div hides and then increase browser size again then div should display back but it does not

How to achieve this ?

```js
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#demo{
   display:block;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        #demo {
            display: none;
        }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">Hello</div>

<span onclick="openNav()">Open</span>
<span onclick="closeNav()">Close</span>
```

Comment: I didn't understand the problem, in the snippet, it seems to work nice... please, explain it better

Comment: I updated my question, hope its clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `min-width` instead of `max-width` to achieve this. I'm also using `!important` which, despite how much I despise, is needed to override the style set by `JavaScript`.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    #demo {
        display: block!important;
    }
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#demo {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  #demo {
    display: block!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">Hello</div>
<span onclick="openNav()">Open</span>
<span onclick="closeNav()">Close</span>
```

Comment: it works thnx. so we need !important to override javascript set style ?

Comment: You're welcome @Raj. I'm glad I could help. Yes, I tested it without `!important` and it didn't work.